# Two Dimension NSMutableArray help?

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Ok, I have some C# code that looks like this and I was wondering what other developers would recommend if I am trying to put this into Objective-C.

```
List<List<string>> meta_data
```

I'm planning on using `NSMutableArray` but how to exactly get that two-dimensional array figured out is my problem, since there is no such thing as a multidimensional array in Objective-C. I'm new to using `NSMutableArray`, so I still need some help every now and then.

I know I will just add string objects to the array using NSString once I have the whole "two-dimensional" part figured out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An array can hold any object.  I'm not familiar with C# code, but I imagine all your trying to do is nested arrays.

What you need to be using is objectAtIndex: for NSArrays.

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello World";
NSMutableArray *insideArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:hello,nil];
NSMutableArray *outsideArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[outsideArray addObject:insideArray];
// Then access it by:
NSString *retrieveString = [[outsideArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

I think your looking for something like that.  Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
//Create the array of strings
NSMutableArray *strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[strings addObject:@"someString"];
[strings addObject:@"someOtherString"];

//Create the array to hold the string array
NSMutableArray *container = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[container addObject:strings];
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays containing NSStrings

Comment: Well I thought about that, but like you said in your comment, (you used the plural form NSMutableArrays)...how am I supposed code it so I can have an arbitrary amount of mutable arrays? The decision as to how many mutable arrays would be needed would be decided at runtime.

Comment: In C#, you add List<String> (List of Strings) objects to your List<List<String>> (List of Lists of Strings) using the add method.

In much the same way, you add NSMutableArray objects containing NSStrings to your NSMutableArray containing NSMutableArray objects.

Pretend for a moment that NSMutableArray is a C# class synonymous with List and NSString is synonymous with String. You would be creating an NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray<NSString>> in C# code.

The answer given by @AlexRozanski does just that, but in Objective-C.