# Array of a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on an iphone app in objective-c and I am having trouble with making an array out of a class variable, for example...

I have a class named `Cube` and I am tryin to make an instance of this class named map that is an array

```
Cube map[10][10];
```

Xcode then says it is an error and suggests I do this

```
Cube *map[10][10];
```

When I do it this way though ^ I cannot access one of my methods I defined in the class `Cube`, now this is not ALL my methods, it is just one single method that wont work anytime I try to call it.  The only thing different about this method than the others is that I pass a parameter to it.  The `Cube` class declaration and definition both compile flawlessly.

Can anyone explain to me how to make a class with a 2 dimensional without turning it into a pointer.  Also why does xcode recommend I make it a pointer, and why doesn't the method work when I do it this way?

Comment: I think you should really read the basics of Objective-C, Foundation and collection classes in particular.

Comment: I know the syntax of objective-c, i also know its supposed to share code seamlessly with C

Comment: The pointer requirement is because all Objective-C objects must be allocated on the heap. I'm curious as to why your one method isn't working when you use `Cube *map[10][10]`; I agree with the others that nested NSArrays would be better, but perhaps you could provide the code of methods that do and don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a Cocoa style array, i.e. `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` instead of C-style array. It is much more flexible and is designed to work with Objective-c objects. Have a look at this simple tutorial on using a Cocoa array: http://iphonelearning.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/nsarray-and-nsmutablearray/.

Comment: How would I make the NSMultableArray an array of the specific class?

Comment: @KingPopsicle -- You wouldn't -- it's an array of NSObject.

Comment: So how do I call my class specific methods if it doesnt implement the specific class?

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach for this in Objective-C is to create an `NSArray(or NSMutableArray)` of an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`).  Assuming you want to be able to manipulate the array after you create the array object, your code would look something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* cubeGrid = [NSMutableArray new]; // Note that this code assumes you are using ARC.

// add row 1
NSMutableArray* cubeRow1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cube1,cube2,cube3,nil]; // you will need to add cube 4 to 10 in the real code
[cubeGrid addObject:cubeRow1];

// add row 2
NSMutableArray* cubeRow2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cube11,cube12,cube13,nil]; // you will need to add cube 14 to 20 in the real code
[cubeGrid addObject:cubeRow2];

// and you will create the rest of the rows and add to the cubeGrid array
```

To access the elements you would do something like this:

```
for (id cubeRow in cubeGrid) {
    if ([cubeRow isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (id cube in (NSArray*)cubeRow) {
            if ([cube isKindOfClass:[Cube class]]) {
                // Do things with cube
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you might also want to double check is whether the method that you are trying to access is declared in the header file.

Comment: Stupid stupid stupid why does objective-c put me through this c is much more? SENSABLE! I will try this code tomorrow, it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114693/1477887) answer.